# Visualise data hierachy with HTML and CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below, is a basic diagram of the layout I have basically I have a parent div, and then within that I have child divs, the layout basically shows the hierachy of some data. What I am wanting to achieve is show that hierachy visually. AS you can see below on the left of each name there is a line what I am wanting is to create this kind of visual using borders, would this possible? I can't even think where I would start.

```
Parent Div 1
    |
    |
    |- Child Div 1.a
    |- Child Div 1.b
       |
       |
       |- Child Child Div 1.1.a
    |
    |
    |
    Parent Div 2
    |
    |
    | - Child Div 2.a
    | - Child Div 2.b
```

Comment: You can check out this [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) plugin.

Comment: Look up the `border-radius` and `text-align` properties in CSS.

Comment: And from where I see it it would be better to user lists (`<ul>` or `<ol>` if there is an order) than `<div>'s` which are kinda "joker" block HTML control but have no semantic meaning

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this css could give you a start?

```
div.tree div.tree {
  margin-left : 20px;    
}
div.tree div.tree:before {
  content:"| ";  /*You can use an image here maybe*/
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P5DAV/1/)**